# How to detect "possibly lost" bytes in valgrind when no sufficient data are provided?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have been digging several days in my 1500 lines of code to find those 15 bytes (possibly lost) to no avail.
There are no sufficient data provided by valgrind even though I ran the following command:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --track-origins=yes --show-below-main=yes ./myapp
```

I get the following block of report:

```
==3283== 15 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1 of 4
==3283==    at 0x402842F: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:255)
==3283==    by 0x40D2A83: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==3283==    by 0x40D4CF7: char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==3283==    by 0x40D4E65: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==3283==    by 0x804DB22: _GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN7processC2Ei7in_addr (main.cpp:1304)
==3283==    by 0x8050131: __libc_csu_init (in /home/username/myapp-write/src/myapp)
==3283==    by 0x41A60A9: __libc_start_main (libc-start.c:185)
==3283==    by 0x80499C0: ??? (in /home/username/myapp-write/src/myapp)
==3283==
```

Would any one, please, tell me how to detect the faulty line?

Comment: Check the std::string allocated at main.cpp:1304.

Comment: Valgrind is telling you exactly where the leak is occurring, what more do you want?

Comment: 1304 is the final line of main.cpp

Comment: @user657267 as you got it, would you please tell me where :)

Comment: @Moi Let me break out my crystal ball. Or you could post your code.

Comment: Does `main()` have *any* alternative exit points as opposed to simply using `return exit-code;` By alternative i mean something *functional*, like an `exit` call or something similar? And post your toolchain please.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, some where I am using std::terminate()

Comment: Any chance you can squelch that and wire up the boolean chain back to `main` for a clean exit via `return` ? May take you a bit of time to rethink the exit strategy. If the terminate calls are actually *in* `main`, replacing them with `return something;` should be quick enough. `std::terminate` defaults to calling `std::abort`, and it does NOT fire destructors of automatic vars.

Comment: You are right, it is solved. would you please post an answer to accept it. You are great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code invokes alternative termination strategies that are *not* designed to properly clean up automatic variables due to hindering unwind semantics, your automatic variable destructors will not be called.

[`std::terminate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate), as you mentioned in-comment you were using, unfortunately ponies up one such condition. The default action for the termination handler is to invoke [`std::abort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort), which does *not* fire cleanup destruction on automatic, thread-local, or static storage duration objects, and any such vars that have assumed dynamic memory management will leak like a sieve.

Avoid termination in this fashion unless you have a *very* good reason for it, and in general there are *very few* good reasons for it.

Best of luck.